# Jmeter jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler in a batch file is running from local command prompt but not from windows command prompt in Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jmeter

I am having a Frame work with relative paths. Jmeter scripts having jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler in headless mode. This batch works fine from local command prompt but when I run the batch file using "Execute Windows batch command" in Jenkins it doesn't works.

Screenshot of batch file execution from command prompt:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHRcr.png)

Screenshot of same batch file execution from Jenkins:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNEUs.png)

As we can see in above screenshot that "org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createsession" is not triggered from jenkins

Framework structure: enter image description here

batch file is available in batch, under tools we have the Jmeter and so on...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12G5E.png)
Screenshot of the commands to call the script from batch file enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWbxQ.png)

Comment: Commands to call the script from batch file:      cd %~dp0..\..\..\..\tools\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin    



waitfor SomethingThatIsNeverHappening /t 30 2>NUL        


call jmeter -p %userPropFile% -Jusers=%VUs% -Jrampup=%rampUpTime% -JloopCount=%loopCount% -JsaveRespPath=%saveRespPath_1% -JbrowserDriverPath=%browserDriverPath% -JtestDataAdminToken=%testDataAdminToken% -JtestDataUserToken=%testDataUserToken% -JtestDataPath=%testDataPath% -JtestDataFile=%testDataFile% -JJsonBodyFilePath=%testDataSet_1% -n -t %jmxFilePath% -l %testResultCSVFilePath_1% -e -o %htmlResultFilePath_1%

Answer (score 0):

Always take a look a [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it should contain at least a clue for the error if not the root cause. If you cannot figure out the reason yourself - add the file to your question so we could take a look.

One of possible reasons I can think of at the moment is that if you installed [Jenkins as the Windows Service](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service) it cannot interact with the desktop so you need to [allow this](https://www.ge.com/digital/documentation/cimplicity/version111/oxy_ex-2/advanced_features/topics/t_cimplicity_advanced_features_step1_turnon_allow_serviceto_interactwith_desktop.html)

Another option is ticking "Use Chrome headless mode" box:

[image]

More information: [Headless Execution of Selenium Tests in Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-execution-selenium-tests-jenkins)